# Внешний ключ между таблицами разных БД

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как создать внешний ключ между таблицами разных БД, которые находятся на одном сервере.СУБД: SQL SERVER

Answer (score 7, accepted):

читайте [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships)

> **Ограничения `FOREIGN KEY` могут ссылаться только на таблицы в пределах
>   той же базы данных на том же сервере.** Межбазовую ссылочную целостность
>   необходимо реализовать посредством триггеров. Дополнительные сведения
>   см. в разделе [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql).

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, указать ссылку, где указывается создание триггера, который именно обеспечивает межбазовую ссылочность.В гугле я покопал, ничего подобного не нашел

Comment: @ДиванныйАналитик дак там же нет никакого волшебного триггера который это делает. Нужно просто написать триггер, который при вставке значений будет проверять наличие этого значения во внешней таблице. С другой стороны надо написать триггер обеспечивающий каскадное обновление/удаление. Сами по себе это обычные триггеры, вручную реализующие сей функционал.

Comment: у меня точно такая мысль была в голове, но все таки решил спросить